# Microsoft Graph Team owner not found for group

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have aproject project in Java. When I run the project I got a error:

> Error message: Team owner not found for group

How to fix it?

```
final ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
.clientId("xxxx")
.clientSecret("yyyy")
.tenantId("zzzzz")
.build();
List scope = new ArrayList<>();
scope.add("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
final TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider( scope, clientSecretCredential);

final GraphServiceClient graphClient =
GraphServiceClient
.builder()
.authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
.buildClient();

Group group = new Group();
group.description = "Group with designated owner and members2025";
group.displayName = "Operations group2025";
LinkedList groupTypesList = new LinkedList();
group.groupTypes = groupTypesList;
group.mailEnabled = false;
group.mailNickname = "operations2025";
group.securityEnabled = true;

group.additionalDataManager().put(""owners@odata.bind"", new JsonPrimitive("[ "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/1111"]"));
group.additionalDataManager().put(""members@odata.bind"", new JsonPrimitive("[ "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/22222"]"));

Team team = new Team();
TeamMemberSettings memberSettings = new TeamMemberSettings();
memberSettings.allowCreateUpdateChannels = true;
team.memberSettings = memberSettings;
TeamMessagingSettings messagingSettings = new TeamMessagingSettings();
messagingSettings.allowUserEditMessages = true;
messagingSettings.allowUserDeleteMessages = true;
team.messagingSettings = messagingSettings;
TeamFunSettings funSettings = new TeamFunSettings();
funSettings.allowGiphy = true;
funSettings.giphyContentRating = GiphyRatingType.STRICT;
team.funSettings = funSettings;

graphClient.groups(graphClient.groups().buildRequest().post(group).id).team()
.buildRequest()
.put(team).id;
```

Message response:

```
2021-08-01 03:08:14.334 ERROR 19944 --- [ main] global : CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 396Graph service exception Error code: BadRequest
2021-08-01 03:08:14.336 ERROR 19944 --- [ main] global : CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 396Error message: Team owner not found for group
```

Comment: As per the [Create group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java#request-1)  document, It is mentioned to use the users graph API. Could you please try this and check if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow sometime once you create group or teams or adding members so that it can reflect properly, as they need to create the objects in backend, sync properly - based on my testing this is what i notice.

Comment: I add a sleep, for the data but it doesn´t work. I changed this line "graphClient.groups(graphClient.groups().buildRequest().post(group).id).team().buildRequest().put(team).id;" for this: try {sleep(120000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();} String idGroup =  graphClient.groups().buildRequest().post(group).id;   String idTeam= graphClient.groups(idGroup).team().buildRequest().put(team).id;